# Ошибка модуля GM в Node.JS

Tags: node.js

```
gm('1.jpg').thumb(250, 250, '1.jpg', 100, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

> { [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }

В чем проблема?

Система windows.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что этот модуль является обверткой для библиотеки GraphicsMagick, следовательно, установите её [win-версию](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/download.html).